# Mysql - if value doesn't exists use another table

Tags: php, mysql, subquery

what I'm trying to do is run a query to display all products 
customers may have discounts for(when they log in) or it just uses the standardTermsPricing:

tables are: 
`product` want to display all
manufacturer, productRange, webcode, description, supplierCode, priceExVat etc

`standardTermsPricing` (this doesn't contain any userid)
`supplier , supplierCode , Amount`

`supplierdiscounts`
`supplier(supplierCode) , user , Amount`

`productdiscounts`
`user ,`product (webcode) , Amount ``

I know user y127 is working at some level but if I try one z999 this isn't in table supplierdiscounts or productDiscounts so no results.

my current select statement doesn't really work it gets some results but not what I want... any ideas??

end result I'm using a PHP mysqli_query to loop results to display to customer and export a CSV file - but that's another issue!!

many thanks, Ian

```
SELECT  
p.name,  
p.manufacturer, 
p.productRange, 
p.webcode, 
p.description, 
p.supplierCode, 
p.priceExVat, 
stp.amount 'standard discount amount', 
sd.amount 'supplier discount amount',
pd.amount 'product discount amount',
sd.user
FROM
products p
  JOIN standardTermsPricing stp ON p.supplierCode  =  stp.supplierCode 
  JOIN supplierdiscounts sd ON p.supplierCode = sd.supplier 
  JOIN productDiscounts pd ON p.webcode = pd.product  
  WHERE  sd.user = 'Y127'
```

Answer (score 0):

[`JOIN`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/join.html) is the same as an `INNER JOIN` so only matching combinations are returned. If you want all rows, also when there are no matching rows in the discounts tables, you need for example a `LEFT JOIN`:

```
...
FROM 
    products p
INNER JOIN standardTermsPricing stp 
  ON p.supplierCode  =  stp.supplierCode 
LEFT JOIN supplierdiscounts sd 
  ON p.supplierCode = sd.supplier 
LEFT JOIN productDiscounts pd 
  ON p.webcode = pd.product  
WHERE sd.user = 'Y127'
```

Comment: thanks that seems to work for when we have a user within the supplierdiscounts or productDiscounts WHERE sd.user = 'Y127' works but no results if WHERE sd.user = 'z999'

Comment: @IanGerdes You are using `sd.user` in your `WHERE` condition, so if there is no record with `sd.user = 'z999' ` you will never get any results. You could put that condition on the join instead, but it depends on what you need to do exactly.

Comment: Hi Jeroen sorry for the late reply I tried putting then sd.user in the join but it crashed out on me. Is there any if value not null show inner join else show standardsterms table?

Comment: @IanGerdes How did it crash out? Using `LEFT JOIN supplierdiscounts sd 
  ON p.supplierCode = sd.supplier AND sd.user = 'Y127'` should work just fine.

Comment: We have thousands of rows to check -- its still loading as I type - going to have to kill it! this with left join as you have it... when we put the ``WHERE sd.user = 'Y127' `` it takes 0.08 seconds to run all.

Comment: @IanGerdes You would have to filter somewhere, and a `WHERE` after the joins is the correct place, but you should not use the `sd` or `pd` tables for the filtering. Instead, filter on something like `p.supplierCode`. And put the other condition on the join like in my previous comment.

Answer (score 0):

fixed it, many thanks - we had some duplicate products in the db.

```
SELECT 
p.name,  
p.manufacturer, 
p.productRange, 
p.webcode, 
p.description, 
p.supplierCode, 
p.priceExVat,
sd.amount sdamount,
pd.amount pdamount,
stp.amount stpamount
FROM products p
INNER JOIN standardTermsPricing stp ON p.supplierCode  =  stp.supplierCode 
LEFT JOIN supplierdiscounts sd ON p.supplierCode = sd.supplier  AND sd.user = 'C456' 
LEFT JOIN productDiscounts pd ON p.webcode = pd.product   AND sd.user = 'C456' 
WHERE sd.user = 'C456' 
UNION
SELECT 
  p.name,  
p.manufacturer, 
p.productRange, 
p.webcode, 
p.description, 
p.supplierCode, 
p.priceExVat,
NULL,
NULL,
stp.amount stpamount
FROM products p
INNER JOIN standardTermsPricing stp ON p.supplierCode  =  stp.supplierCode
```